# The Extension "VMAccessForLinux" Enable Failed

Tags: azure

Recently I provisioning one Linux virtual machine (Centos 7/Resource Manager) from the custom VHD file which uploaded into Azure storage blob. Everything seem fine except two issue I observed below:

Issue 1: Manually installed the latest VM agent for linux first, but no matter I use the powershell command or through the portal to reset the user password, it always get failed with below error message found in extension log.

```
2016/11/23 15:25:10 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] sequence number is 0
2016/11/23 15:25:10 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] setting file path is/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0/c onfig/0.settings
2016/11/23 15:25:10 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] JSON con fig: {"runtimeSettings": [{"handlerSettings": {"protectedSettings": "MIIB4AYJKoZ IhvcNAQcDoIIB0TCCAc0CAQAxggFpMIIBZQIBADBNMDkxNzA1BgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFidXaW5kb3dzIEF 6dXJlIENSUCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBHZW5lcmF0b3ICEF53i2Gow5OnR8IvFRsSasswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQE BBQAEggEAiGxKv6VTW5IluLGMZ26eJnXToWQxzY1oTtVnKQf1snHEV7JBaDoPJlM2NuInvDXs1rA51RD lAU17Og9rDLm3NTem55WyRG9ANT87mf869vdL/M5fdZhB9QbO1aJTCkBn2bpnps5t7X8lCUfGekrAeMD hACnrZKlaKlmkxPN7YX/ARBsD9TyVrauXz7fshVOT8PeVvxue8C+MddM58ot6N98gt3HueEH1GxTzuiH CSuLXSN34qeRPQ46Jbz1IiF0y08t1JFGqcNZvcn2P4UWr3bx34xiEm6M0VYKX5LXMNiemWI9K/bgcpJ8 jpZRMPrx/tmkVHFhPe1MCqu/3BY2l8DBbBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECENgdMLZao8ugDg jt+RrqDVVWuCtp9DiWxm5D05974fSO9Ssv2tk5n7R1gmr3vtnBSATRD4VFdJKzrYw97ox3iGAtg==", "publicSettings": {}, "protectedSettingsCertThumbprint": "4546850E7C0933BE6145AE 51035EF8D4D5DEFFB5"}}]}
2016/11/23 15:25:10 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] Config d ecoded correctly.
2016/11/23 15:25:10 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] Install, success,0,Install Succeeded
2016/11/23 15:25:11 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] sequence number is 0
2016/11/23 15:25:11 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] setting file path is/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0/c onfig/0.settings
2016/11/23 15:25:11 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] JSON con fig: {"runtimeSettings": [{"handlerSettings": {"protectedSettings": "MIIB4AYJKoZ IhvcNAQcDoIIB0TCCAc0CAQAxggFpMIIBZQIBADBNMDkxNzA1BgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFidXaW5kb3dzIEF 6dXJlIENSUCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0ZSBHZW5lcmF0b3ICEF53i2Gow5OnR8IvFRsSasswDQYJKoZIhvcNAQE BBQAEggEAiGxKv6VTW5IluLGMZ26eJnXToWQxzY1oTtVnKQf1snHEV7JBaDoPJlM2NuInvDXs1rA51RD lAU17Og9rDLm3NTem55WyRG9ANT87mf869vdL/M5fdZhB9QbO1aJTCkBn2bpnps5t7X8lCUfGekrAeMD hACnrZKlaKlmkxPN7YX/ARBsD9TyVrauXz7fshVOT8PeVvxue8C+MddM58ot6N98gt3HueEH1GxTzuiH CSuLXSN34qeRPQ46Jbz1IiF0y08t1JFGqcNZvcn2P4UWr3bx34xiEm6M0VYKX5LXMNiemWI9K/bgcpJ8 jpZRMPrx/tmkVHFhPe1MCqu/3BY2l8DBbBgkqhkiG9w0BBwEwFAYIKoZIhvcNAwcECENgdMLZao8ugDg jt+RrqDVVWuCtp9DiWxm5D05974fSO9Ssv2tk5n7R1gmr3vtnBSATRD4VFdJKzrYw97ox3iGAtg==", "publicSettings": {}, "protectedSettingsCertThumbprint": "4546850E7C0933BE6145AE 51035EF8D4D5DEFFB5"}}]}
2016/11/23 15:25:11 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] Config d ecoded correctly.
2016/11/23 15:25:11 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] set most recent sequence number to 0
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR:[Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] Fa iled to enable the extension with error: no element found: line 22, column 31, s tack trace: Traceback (most recent call last):
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: File "/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAc cessForLinux-1.4.6.0/./vmaccess.py", line 96, in enable
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: _set_user_account_pub_key(protect_settings, hutil)
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: File "/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAc cessForLinux-1.4.6.0/./vmaccess.py", line 162, in _set_user_account_pub_key
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: ovf_env = waagent.OvfEnv().Parse(ovf_xml)
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: File "/var/lib/waagent/Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAc cessForLinux-1.4.6.0/waagent", line 4778, in Parse
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(xmlText)
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py", line 1931, in parseString
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: return expatbuilder.parseString(string)
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 940, in parseString
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: return builder.parseString(string)
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xml/dom/expatbuilder.py", line 223, in parseString
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR: parser.Parse(string, True)
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR:ExpatError: no element found: line 22, column 31
2016/11/23 15:25:11 ERROR:
2016/11/23 15:25:11 [Microsoft.OSTCExtensions.VMAccessForLinux-1.4.6.0] Enable,e rror,0,Enable failed.
```

Meanwhile the VM cannot restart through the portal
I tried to remove extension then run the command again but issue persist still. Can anyone advise how can I resolved such issue? Thanks a lot!!

Issue 2: The computer name is blank on the portal, I guess it might involves to the custom image or any agent or extension not work properly , because other VMs provision from the Azure image gallery has no such issue. Please advise.... thanks!

Comment: Thanks David help to optimize the post format. sorry it's my first time to raise question here. After analysis more logs, issue might relate to ovf-env.xml file missing.  original log here:  ******2016/11/22 17:30:30.609194 ERROR Event: name=WALA, op=Provision, message=Failed to copy ovf-env.xml: (000008)(000007)Failed to get dvd device******

Answer (score 0):

The issue 1 is resolved after I manually copy ovf-env.xml from another Azure VM(Working Fine) to current one, also need to modify ovf-env.xml such like hostname and username to ensure such setting match current VM environment. After the fix, both "Restart" button and feature "Reset Password" come back to work on Azure portal! But now I'm struggling with issue 2 that "Computer Name" is empty on the portal. will keep posting if have any further update. please please if you have any good idea or expertise please write down here! Thanks!